# Marketing Cloud - update a Data Extension field via SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I have a **SOAP** request and I want to **replace** the value in the existing field for the Data Extension Object that I have. It seems to give me a response of "**OK**" but I do no see that change in the field value in my Data Extension Object.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this or if I need to change anything -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
 <fueloauth> abcd </fueloauth>
 </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options>
      <SaveOptions>
        <SaveOption>
          <PropertyName>DataExtensionObject</PropertyName>
          <SaveAction>UpdateOnly</SaveAction>
        </SaveOption>
      </SaveOptions>
      <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
    </Options>
        <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <Client>
           <ID>12345</ID>
        </Client>
        <CustomerKey>abc_pqr_xyz</CustomerKey>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <Email>replacement1234567@abcd.com</Email>       
        <Attributes>
          <Attribute>
            <Name>Email</Name>
            <Value>replacement1@abcd.com</Value>
          </Attribute>
          </Attributes>
        </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I would try changing the request type to Synchronous as a test to see if you get a better error message.

Comment: @Tyler I still get the same message even if it is 'Synchronous'. 
Just the difference is - for 'Asynchronous' - it says 'It will get updated soon' but never gets updated and for 'Synchronous' it says - Updated but nothing gets updated in my field value. The value in the field is still the same as the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone looking for an answer to the above question - the below code worked -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
 <fueloauth>Add your appropriate authentication key/code here which you might be using</fueloauth>
 </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options>
      <SaveOptions>
        <SaveOption>
          <PropertyName>DataExtensionObject</PropertyName>
          <SaveAction>UpdateOnly</SaveAction>
        </SaveOption>
      </SaveOptions>
      <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
    </Options>
        <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <Client>
           <ID>7209246</ID>
        </Client>
        <CustomerKey>abcd_pqrs</CustomerKey>
        <Properties>
          <Property>
            <Name>Subscriber_key</Name>
            <Value>replacement12@frontburnerbrands.com</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>Email</Name>
            <Value>test11@gmail.com</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>First_Name</Name>
            <Value>TestFirstName3</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>Last_Name</Name>
            <Value>TestLastName3</Value>
          </Property>
        </Properties>
        </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```